# Add Next Page' and Previous Page buttons to a Formsite form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am very uneducated when it comes to HTML and CSS, but I currently use the Form provider [Formsite](https://www.formsite.com/).

On the forms I have created the navigation buttons for going to the next and previous page and they are located by default at the bottom of the page. I would also like those at the top of the page of the form.

There is an advanced edit function for CSS And a 'HTML HEAD' I have played around with these and have managed to get some buttons on there, but I can't get them to do anything" I've tried incorporating the FormAction that I see when I inspect the existing buttons, but that hasn't worked.

this is my very poor first attempt, code in HTML HEAD:

```
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outside_container">
        <form action="your_form_processing_script.php" method="post">
            <!-- Your form fields go here -->

            <!-- Submit button at the top -->
            <input type="submit" class="submit_button submit_button_top" value="Next Page">

            <!-- Your form fields go here -->

            <!-- Submit button at the bottom -->
            <input type="submit" class="submit_button submit_button_bottom" value="Previous Page">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Two questions really:

1. Is what I'm trying to do possible? or am I only ever going to be able to edit he appearance of the form?
2. Am I at all close to achieving my goal with the above code?

Comment: _"code in HTML HEAD"_ - if this actually inserts into the `head` element of the page(?), then that of course makes no sense to begin with - you can't stick a `body` element _into_ the head.